# Determine if I have consecutively increasing values

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SQL table that has date (day), location, and value.  The table is ordered by date then location.  I am wanting to find out if out of 9 consecutive dates, the values are all increasing or not (so I can flag them in my eventual chart).  If 9 values are increasing, on the 9th day I want it to flag in a new column.  It will be a rolling 9 days throughout the entire time period.  I also am trying to figure out if in a group of 3 days, 2/3 of the values are over X limit.  (WECO rules, basically)  Suggestions for an approach would be greatly appreciated!  I'm using SQL  Management Studio and/or SSIS or SSRS.  Thanks!

Comment: "SQL" is not the name of a database server. Which database server are you using? SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: Please post some sample data. A SQL Fiddle or sample inserts make these things much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Create a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Weco](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [aDate] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
) 
);
```

-- insert data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Weco] 
VALUES 
('2012-01-01'), ('2012-01-02'), ('2012-01-03'), ('2012-01-04');
```

--Run this query. This should give you some idea

```
SELECT
    W1.ID, W1.[aDate] , DATEDIFF (d,W1.aDate, W2.aDate)
FROM [dbo].[Weco] W1
--inner join 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
         W2.ID, 
         W2.[aDate]
    FROM [dbo].[Weco] W2
    WHERE W2.ID > (SELECT MIN (ID)FROM [dbo].[Weco])
) W2 on W1.ID = W2.ID - 1
```